# Checking flash file loading with javascript

Tags: javascript, flash, download, load

Is there a way to check how much a flash file is (down)loaded to the page before it is shown?
Our team cant put loading indicator inside the flash file because the swf file is uploaded by our client. Is there some kind of property on xmlhttprequest that we can use to indicate how much has been downloaded?
Or any other suggestion to indicate on-screen the loaded percentage?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have control over how the file is loaded in the browser? i have a theory that you could create a second flash movie, that would load the clients movie into it, and during that process you could show a progress indicator.

Flash has support for loading external .swf files, look [here](http://kb.adobe.com/selfservice/viewContent.do?externalId=tn_14190) to see how.

Comment: i agree - this is what i'd do too.